# How to combine properties in Powershell from multiple Objects

Tags: exchange, powershell, exchange-2010, scripting

Many times I've needed to combine data that can only be retrieved from two separate powershell CMDLETs into a single dataset for export. I believe this should be do-able by creating a PSObject and collecting data there, then selecting data from the PSOBject and exporting it.

An example of what I'm trying to do. This does not work yet.

```
$OU1 = 'Contoso.com/Contoso Service Accounts'
$MBXStats = get-mailbox -OrganizationalUnit $OU1 | Get-MailboxStatistics
$MBXDN = get-mailbox -OrganizationalUnit $OU1 | Select DistinguishedName

$bucket = @()

foreach ($MBX in $MBXStats){

$PropertyObj = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    DisplayName = $MBXStats.DisplayName
    ItemCount = $MBXStats.ItemCount
    TotalItemSize = $MBXStats.TotalItemSize
    LastLogonTime = $MBXStats.LastLogonTime
    OriginatingServer = $MBXStats.OriginatingServer
    DistinguishedName = $MBXProps.DistinguishedName
    }
    $bucket += $PropertyObj
}

$bucket | Out-GridView
```

I have no idea how to even begin integrating the datagathering for `$MBXDN = get-mailbox -OrganizationalUnit $OU1 | Select DistinguishedName` into the script.

Comment: Please help us to help you by providing correct data. The question is about combining properties from multiple objects but object $MBXProps you refer to is not defined in your code example while object $Mbxdn is not used at al

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to combine properties from multiple objects onto the output stream.  I think the best way to accomplish your goal is to leverage calculated properties on your pipeline.  However, in your code example `MBXProps` is an undeclared variable which may be the leading cause to why your process isn't working.  Though you've likely cherry picked what code to show us (generally a bad idea) so I'll assume you're trying to integrate the MBX DN with your dataset.

```
$MBXStats = get-mailbox -OrganizationalUnit $OU1 | Get-MailboxStatistics
$MBXDN = get-mailbox -OrganizationalUnit $OU1 | Select DistinguishedName

$MBXStats | Select *,@{N="DistinguishedName";E="$($MBXDN.DistinguishedName)"}
```

Summarily, what you want to do is add a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to the output.  I'm being slightly lazy by valuing all `*` properties and not your chosen few, but you can adapt it to your needs.  Of note you should try to always output objects to leverage the true power of Powershell.